# Wordpress programming by php

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, action

I have defined a hook (action) in my 'functions.php' file in Salient template. I have written these at the bottom of the that file:

```
add_action('message','example_function');

function example_function()
{
    echo "hello world";
}
```

I have added these below code in my template 'index.php' file:

```
<?php
    do_action( 'message' );
?>
```

But nothing happens on start of my wordpress site, Any hint?

Comment: Your code is working fine in my local.add exit(); on page then check.

Comment: I don's see anything wrong with the above code. Where in the `index.php` have you added the `do_action()`? Could the result be printed but hidden behind some element?

Comment: Check if a JS alert works. `echo "<script>alert('hello world');</script>";`

Comment: The main point behind this question is where to put add_action() and do_action() functions in wordpress files, I have written add_action() in 'functions.php' and do_action() in 'single.php' or 'index.php' and now it is OK,

Answer (score 0):

The main point behind this question is where to put add_action() and do_action() functions in wordpress files, I have written add_action() in 'functions.php' and do_action() in 'single.php' or 'index.php' and now it is OK, I guess it is very obscure and ambiguous that what is the role of each php file in wordpress.